# How to find the length of an input string without using standard length function in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, plsql

Is there a way to know the string length by writing PL/SQL function, without using LENGTH()?

Comment: Please explain why the standard function does not meet your purposes?

Comment: It was asked in an interview. Exploring if there is a way..

Comment: @LukStorms, that’s the standard function I wanna avoid here..

Comment: Ok, figured it was odd that you first asked to replace the strlen Pro*C function.

Comment: Create a loop and substring each character while incrementing the counter. Return the counter as a result from function. Beware about length in characters vs length in bytes though.

Comment: @LukStorms, DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH is also a standard function, so the purpose is to avoid it. Looking for a way through a pl/sql function which accepts the string and processes the string inside it’s 'begin..end' block to return the length of the input string.

Comment: @KamilG., probably that’s the logic I need to follow to get the length.. Thanks!

Comment: If in an interview I'd have been asked not to use a standard library function I'd first ask: _"Please explain why the standard function does not meet your purposes?"_.

Comment: I'm sure there are lots of ways. For example, you could concatenate `'#'` on the end of the string, use `instr()` with a negative position argument to find the last `'#'`, and subtract 1. Or use `regexp_count()` to search for `'.'`, with maybe an `nvl()` to handle empty strings. (Neither of these is specifically PL/SQL though.)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, I agree with all the above ways.. thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mylength (p_text IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN INTEGER
AS
   l_ret   INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
   WHILE SUBSTR (p_text, l_ret + 1, 1) IS NOT NULL
   LOOP
      l_ret   := l_ret + 1;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN l_ret;
END mylength;

BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('ABC: ' || mylength ('ABC'));
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('ABCDEFG: ' || mylength ('ABCDEFG'));
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('empty: ' || mylength (''));
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('null: ' || mylength (NULL));
END;

ABC: 3
ABCDEFG: 7
empty: 0
null: 0
```